# How to make GraphQL resolver for list of objects returned by API using Apollo?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, apollo-server

I am new to GraphQL and want to run my first app. I have seen several examples but they have used several libraries and i just want simple example.
I have seen https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hLcAlln-D_s

My Index.js code

```
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require("apollo-server");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");    
const typeDefs = `
  type Query {   
    getApplicant: [Applicant]
  }
  type Applicant {
    FiscalYear:String
    JobNumber: String
    JobDescription: String
    AppsReceived: Int
    Female: Int
    Male: Int
    UnknownGender: Int
    Black: Int
    Hispanic: Int
    Asian: Int
    Caucasian: Int 
    AmericanIndian:Int
    Filipino: Int
    UnknownEthnicity: Int    
  } `;
const url = `http://localhost:52993/api/values`;    
const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        getApplicant: async () => {
            const response = await fetch(url).then(res => res.json());
            console.log(response);
            return response;                
        }
    }
};
const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });
server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
    console.log(`  Server ready at ${url}`);
});
```

Data returned from API

```
[{   "FiscalYear": "2013-2014",
    "JobNumber": "9206 OP 2014/04/18",
    "JobDescription": "311 DIRECTOR 9206",
    "AppsReceived": 54,
    "Female": 20,
    "Male": 31,
    "UnknownGender": 3,
    "Black": 25,
    "Hispanic": 18,
    "Asian": 1,
    "Caucasian": 6,
    "AmericanIndian": 0,
    "Filipino": 0,
    "UnknownEthnicity": 4
  },
  {
    "FiscalYear": "2013-2014",
    "JobNumber": "1223 P 2013/08/09",
    "JobDescription": "ACCOUNTING CLERK 1223",
    "AppsReceived": 648,
    "Female": 488,
    "Male": 152,
    "UnknownGender": 8,
    "Black": 151,
    "Hispanic": 204,
    "Asian": 123,
    "Caucasian": 62,
    "AmericanIndian": 3,
    "Filipino": 79,
    "UnknownEthnicity": 26
  }]
```

when I query data it always displays null.What I am missing?

Comment: Try Changing the query as type Query {  getApplicant: [Applicant] }.

Comment: I'm with @Indragith here, you need to specify that the result of your query is an array, `[Applicant]`

Comment: I changed it to [Applicant].... but still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried another API and it worked well with the same code, just changed the schema related things. Although my .net core Web API was returning same data as mentioned but to make my resolver work, I did 2 things

1. I returned the following from the API Get method:

   ```
   var myJObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Applicant>>(json);
   return Ok(myJObject);
   ```
2. In schema I modified "Applicant" properties to camel case. As I saw my API was returning camel case properties which are not getting mapped to my "Applicant" schema

I spent hours on that so I found it worth sharing.